# Why is it incorrect to say "I have an available room"

Tags: adjectives

I have a guesthouse and I have a sign saying "available room". Someone told me better to say "room available" Why is this?

Comment: Signs are common to be  written in short form with _be_ verbs or generally _function words_ dropped e.g. _waitress wanted, evenings and weekends_ which is actually _a waitress is wanted here in the evening and on the weekend_, so _room availabe_ is short for _a room (to rent) is available_. _Available room_ is more like labeling a room (this is an available room) than a sign reading _a room is available to rent_.

Comment: @Yuri - That's true, and a good point, but I'd say "room available" even if it wasn't on a sign, e.g., "I hear that you're looking for a place to stay, and it just so happens that I have a **room available** that you might like."

Comment: I feel like this is idiomatic, meaning there is no reason for it.  It's just "what people say".  After all you wouldn't say to a hungry friend, "Here, I have a sandwich uneaten."

Comment: @stangdon right, didn't see it that way as in _There are plenty of jobs available in the area._. A good point. Thanks.

Comment: @stangdon I don't think that's really related though. That's just a possible position for modifiers in a normal sentence, but I was tempted to retag this question as [headlinese].

Comment: Because ***available*** is a relatively uncommon adjective, it might help to compare *I have **an empty room** next week* with *I have **a room empty** next week*.

Comment: There's a difference between "I have an available room" and "available room". Which is it that you're asking about?

Answer (score 4):

This [source](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=mo_dCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA112&lpg=PA112&dq=postpositive%20adjectives%20quirk&source=bl&ots=yjsbglJ7NP&sig=6xxp_WQ8dVOzB0jglSmjXnTVkZA&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC557u-bXSAhVLf5AKHYs9A-UQ6AEIQzAG#v=onepage&q=postpositive%20adjectives%20quirk&f=false) makes a good classification of adjectives into attributive (premodifying the noun), postpositive (postmodifying the noun), and predicative (those which modify the subject being inside the predicate).

"available" is mentioned as a typically postpositive adjective and, in line with one of the comments above, it is used in that position because it is merely more idiomatic (the source says that postpositive adjectives "are normally found in a number of **fixed expressions**"). The adjective "available" is in fact usually found after the noun to which it refers: *We have a room available / There is a room available.*

Comment: "available equipment" is grammatical IMO. "available" does appear as an  attributive modifier.

Comment: @M.A.R. Of course it is grammatical. The fact that it is more usually found in post-position does not mean it is incorrect or never found in attributive position. In the Corpus examples at the foot of this entry (http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/available) there are a few examples of "available" in attributive position, but most of them are in post- or predicative position.

Comment: Oh, I misread your answer. I thought you implied it's ungrammatical. Sorry.